# error when starting dev server:Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup[as oncomplete](node:internal/dns/promises:82:17)

Tags: server, dns, localhost, getaddrinfo, enotfound-error

me da error abrir cualquier proyecto en Visual….

error when starting dev server:
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:internal/dns/promises:82:17)

ESTO ES LO QUE ME DICE CUANDO SIGO LOS PASOS:

Guest@iMac-de-Tamara-2 principium % npm run dev

> principium@0.0.0 dev
> vite

sh: vite: command not found
Guest@iMac-de-Tamara-2 principium % npm install

added 102 packages, and audited 103 packages in 3s

21 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

1 high severity vulnerability

To address all issues, run:
npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.
npm notice
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 10.2.4 -> 10.5.0
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.5.0
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@10.5.0 to update!
npm notice
Guest@iMac-de-Tamara-2 principium % npm audit fix

changed 3 packages, and audited 103 packages in 3s

21 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
Guest@iMac-de-Tamara-2 principium % npm run dev

> principium@0.0.0 dev
> vite

error when starting dev server:
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:internal/dns/promises:82:17)
Guest@iMac-de-Tamara-2 principium % npm run dev

> principium@0.0.0 dev
> vite

error when starting dev server:
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:internal/dns/promises:82:17)
Guest@iMac-de-Tamara-2 principium % --ignore-platform-reqs
__vsc_escape_value:print:21: bad option: -g
zsh: command not found: --ignore-platform-reqs
Guest@iMac-de-Tamara-2 principium % --ignore-platform-reqs
__vsc_escape_value:print:21: bad option: -g
zsh: command not found: --ignore-platform-reqs
Guest@iMac-de-Tamara-2 principium % npm run dev

> principium@0.0.0 dev
> vite

error when starting dev server:
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:internal/dns/promises:82:17)
Guest@iMac-de-Tamara-2 principium %

HE INTENTADO DESCARGAR DE NUEVO LA APLICACION VISUAL STUDIO CODE Y SIGUE EL PROBLEMA...